# "Top users" for this week is completely messed up

Tags: bug, status-declined, reputation, top-users

When I visit [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week), showing the total reputation for the week per-user, the numbers are all messed up.

For some users, it shows much more than just the total rep for this week, while for others (including me), it shows the correct number (the number for this week *only*.).

For example, for the top user, [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen), it shows 2,759 rep, but since Sunday (the start of the week per SO), they've only made 745 rep. **!?!?**

For *me* though, it shows the correct number, 995. **!?!?!?!?**

My guess is that it's related to the recent [SE infrastructure issue/DDoS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377143/1136431), because I've also noticed that the day of and after that, the tag scores on users' profiles didn't update.

Incidental note: yesterday, [Corralien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15239951/corralien) was also being shown as having 2k for this week, like Frank, but today they were updated and are now back to normal, like me.

Comment: Seems to be already reported and [meta-tag:status-review] on MSE: [Problem with reputation earned this week](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/377132/289905).

Comment: Ah, interesting! Indeed that's the problem, and the cause was similar to what I expected. However, why has it been reset for some users?

Comment: @richardec That's covered in the answer: *"Some users will also self-correct in the meantime if reputation recalcs happen for other reasons (such as post deletion, user merges, etc)"*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known bug affecting the weekly "top users" leaderboard. The server-side script that calculates these attempted to run during some downtime caused by a DDoS attack. The team has decided to leave it be and not force a re-calculation. Some users' information will be correct because of re-calculations triggered by other system processes, but other users' information will be wrong, at least until we roll over to next week.

See more detailed information in Adam Lear's answer to the bug report on the über-Meta:
[Problem with reputation earned this week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377132)